# Accord du verbe « pouvoir » au participe passé (féminin)

Tags: orthographe, accord, conjugaison, participe-passé

J'hésite à écrire

> ... comme la précédente que nous n'aurions jamais **pue** nous offrir

Si je remplace le verbe pouvoir par prendre, l'accord féminin est alors logique : "que nous n'aurions jamais prise".  C'est pourquoi j'ai écrit "pue" avec un "e" mais est-ce bien comme ça que s'écrit le féminin du participé passé de *pouvoir* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le remplacement n'est pas valide ici car *prendre* ne peut pas être suivi d'une [proposition infinitive](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_infinitive). C'est cette proposition qui est ici le complément direct, et il ne peut y avoir d'accord. En effet, *la précédente* est le complément non d'*aurions pu*, mais d'*offrir*.

Ajout: je précise (au cas où ce n'était pas clair) qu'il peut y avoir accord avec d'autre verbes (comme voir ou entendre). La règle qui s'applique [est décrite ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_du_participe_pass%C3%A9_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Le_participe_pass%C3%A9_est_plac%C3%A9_devant_un_infinitif).

Comment: Merci beaucoup !